# Debian Stretch Problems

Tags: debian-stretch

I was trying to install `php7.2`, but I could not.

Then I typed this:

```
lsb_release -a
```

And this error occurs:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux stable-updates (sid)
Release:    stable-updates
Codename:   sid
```

How can I return it to the stable version?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i research, there is not an unique answer to your problem, if those answers does not work to you, try `cat /etc/os-release`

If that does not works to you either, you can check [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2365934).